# PHP submission not working with either $_POST or $_REQUEST

Tags: php, submit

I have been trying to get the PHP code to submit an email to a mysqlDB, but for some reason it is not working:

This is the form code in the HTML

```
        <form class="header-signup" action="registration.php" method="post">
            <input name="email" class="input-side" type="email" placeholder="Sign up now">
            <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn-side">
            <p class="hs-disclaimer">No spam, ever. That's a pinky promise.</p>
        </form>
```

For the PHP, I did the following (DB connection infos set to xxxxx):

```
<?php     //start php tag
//include connect.php page for database connection

$hostname="xxxxxx";
$username="xxxxxx";
$password="xxxxxx";
$dbname="xxxxxx";

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Include('connect.php');
//if submit is not blanked i.e. it is clicked.

If(isset($_POST['submit'])!='')
    {
    If($_POST['email']=='')
        {
            Echo "please fill the empty field.";
        }
    Else
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO MailingList (MAIL) VALUES('".$_POST['email']."')";
            $res=mysql_query($sql);
            If($res)
                    {
                        Echo "Record successfully inserted";
                    }
                Else
                    {
                        Echo "There is some problem in inserting record";
                    }

        }
}

?>
```

Do you know what might be the problem?
The php file is in the same folder than the webpage.

Thanks for your time

Regards

Comment: "is not working..." is not a useul description of your problem, what errors are you getting, what actually happens when you click the submit button?

Comment: Please reconsider using the `mysql_*` functions. From the PHP docs: `This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API. `

Comment: You got some error? please write `or die(mysql_error())` after the `mysql_query`

Comment: It's coming from `isset($_POST['submit'])!=''` => `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: Dump `$_POST` in registration.php to make sure you have the values you are expecting.

Comment: @Debflav thats a logic error, but wont stop the execution of the script, as `(if bool != empty string)` will always be true

Comment: @user574632 Oh yes, I've didn't notice that `(true != '')` is true. like `(true !== '')`is true too. It's a strange behavior... Anyway I guess Poomrokc found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $_POST['submit']
```

does not exist, you have to specify the name for the submit button

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit"........>
```

Please try this

Comment: Pretty much this. Since your submit button doesn't have the name property it is never sent by the form. Be careful however, since the value will be equal to the submit button's text. If you plan on having multiple forms with a submit button the first if condition will always be true.

Comment: @EugenTimm That's right haha , I've been through this problem once so I notice it quite fast Xb

Comment: Hello, I tried it but it is not working. The email and submit seems to be empty all the time with POST. I am not sure if this is because I am using the gumby framework

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this conditional for a POST request

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
```

And check the input with a `var_dump($_POST);` to see if the value exists in the array.

This is only if you're expecting one form. If you want multiple forms on the page you could make use of naming your submit button in the HTML code

```
<form class="header-signup" action="registration.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="action1" value="Go" class="btn-side">
</form>
```

You could also use this if you set an name on the submit button

```
if(isset($_POST['action1']))
{
    var_dump("hit");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems that the 'email' or the 'submit' are not being picked. It seems the email is always empty and submit always empty. As if the form names are not being trasnfered to the PHP file. Do you know the possible reason? I did the var_dump and showed that the values are empty

Comment: The var_dump will only work when there is post data available else it returns null. I've made an example where you could check the data once the form is submitted. [http://pastebin.com/2Mi1y90t](http://pastebin.com/2Mi1y90t)